# How to use OnComplete( ) in Cypress?

Tags: typescript, migration, cucumber, cypress

```
onComplete: () => {
    attachReportToTestPlan(); //method call to attach cucumber report to Test Plan
  }
```

The above code was used in Protractor,onComplete waits for the cucumber report to be generated and then attach method is called.
I am migrating Protractor to Cypress (Cypress 12,cypress-cucumber-preprocessor),
Is there any way we can have similar code used/Wait for all the scenario and cucumber report to be generated then invoke the attach report method

Note I am invoking report generation with command **npm run cucumber-report**

I tried using following in cypress.config.ts

```
on("task", {
        onComplete(){
         attachReportToTestPlan();
        }
      });
```

But this is not invoked. I am using below to generate cucumber report
After running this npm command ,test stops and onComplete is not invoked

```
"scripts": {
    "cucumber-report": "node cucumber-html-report.js",
}
```